Movie in which the main characters film a fictious war
I remember that the characters were filming scenes of a destroyed city. They were trying to convince people that a war is taking place in East Europe.
In particular I remember a scene in which a girl is running through the ruins carrying a cat. The director of the scene discuss with another character whether it is an appropriate cat or if it would be better a three-colored cat

I watched this movie on TV with my mother before of 2005 when I was a kid. But the movie could be older. I think I was 7-10 years old.
The movie is in color.
I would say that it was American. 
It was a comedy.


Hi and welcome to M&TV. This could be answered, but do you remember anything else? Other scenes\plot points? The actors\characters or their appearance?

I am really sorry, but no. I think I was 7-10 years old and that is all I can remember.

OK, thanks for replying. Spruced it up as best I can and answer below.

This is the great satire Wag The Dog from 1997 with Dustin Hoffman and Robert De Niro.

Shortly before an election, a spin-doctor and a Hollywood producer join efforts to fabricate a war in order to cover up a presidential sex scandal.

I pretty much watch it every year. It never gets old; sadly, it only gets more relevant each year. Actually, the film was so astute it came out before the Monica Lewinsky scandal and anticipated it. Here's the scene with the cat; the 'refugee' is played by a young Kirsten Dunst:




..and Kirsten Dunst was the girl with the cat!
